# MVC 3 Partial View within dialog not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a datatable webpage that shows a list of user in a datatable.  On the user page there is a button create new user.  On clicking this launches a modal jQuery dialog box for the user to enter details off the new user.  There is a Cancel button which just closes the dialog box and a Save User button which on clicking calls DoSaveUser method in my controller.  I can see from debugging that I get into the DoSaveUser method which should at the end return to a PartialView if the create user was successful saying User was saved.  However my dialog were you enter details is not getting replaced with the Success message - even though the user is getting created - i.e - after I hit the save button - if I then cancel the dialog and refresh the original user page I can see the datatable updated with my new user.

Code on UserList page (there are more fields in the dialog than just forename but have removed them to make question have less code).  So when CreateUser button is clicked my newUserDialog is launched.

```
<div id="newUserDialog">

@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSaveUser", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saveForm" }))
{

     <div id="resultContainer">
        <table class="ui-widget-content" style="width: 565px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                </td>
                <td class="label">
                    Forename :
                </td>
                <td class="value">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Forename, new { style = "width:150px" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="ui-widget-content Rounded" style="width: 565px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
            <input id="Cancel" type="button" class="dialog-button" value="Cancel" style="margin: 5px" />
            <input id="DoSaveUser" type="submit" class="dialog-button" value="Save User" style="margin: 5px" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Javascript code for Save User on the dialog being clicked - submit the form.

```
$(function () {
    $('#saveForm').submit(function () {

        var formData = $("#saveForm").serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#resultContainer').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now in My DoSaveUser method in my controller which I can set a breakpoint and hit and see all the values being sent in correctly for the corresponding fields - once I have saved to the DB this is return.

```
return PartialView("UserSuccess", model);
```

And this is all that view contains in the cshtml..note what I wanted was the result container Div which contains all my textbox fields and labels to be replaced with User Created successfully.  And then I will need an ok on this page which on clicking will close the dialog box and refresh the UserList page and show the datatable updated with the new user.  However when I click save the textboxes just stay on the Div and the Div does not get changed - but if I then cancel the dialog and refresh the page I can see the datatable updated with my new user.  Is there something I am missing? (note - i have added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js to my _Layout page)

```
@model MyProject.Models.UserModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserSuccess";
}
 <div id="resultContainer">
User Created Successfully
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your initial html do have a `#resultContainer` div? If you don't the

```
$('#resultContainer').html(result);
```

line won't match anything. If you do on the other hand, you will get duplicate nested `#resultContainer` divs which is also an error (id must  be unique).

The right way to do it is to add an empty `div` in your original html:

```
<div id="resultContainer"></div>
```

And in your view output just the *content*  to go inside the div.

```
@model MyProject.Models.UserModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserSuccess";
}
User Created Successfully
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I have edited the code as per your suggestion (yes my inital page had the #resultContainer div - see it just after the using { - but as you suggested i had closed it probably in the incorrect place - it is now closed in the same line as you have suggested and removed from the Partial view page - however still dont get it to work.  one thing is I have added an alert to      success: function (result) { alert('I am here');
                $('#resultContainer').html(result);
            } which never pops up on my page???

Comment: Then your success handler is obviously never called. Does your html view return without errors? Press Ctrl+Alt+E and enable break on exceptions to see in the debugger if you have an exception in the view.

Comment: Cheers - just realised I have been stupid - I have my JS for that submit in an extra function declaration that is not needed as my JS is in a different file which contains document.ready declaration at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say what you are doing is not a good way of using dialog and partial view in ASP.NET MVC applications. I can give you some simple code to show an idea:

If list.cshtml is a list of users page, and edit.cshtml is a partial view that has an edit form in.

On list page:

```
$(".grid-row .edit").click(function(){
    editUser($(this).attr("data-id"));
});
function editUser(id){
  var $dialog=$("#dialogEditUser");
  if($dialog.length == 0){
    $dialog=$("<div id='dialogEditUser'>").appendTo("body");
  }
  $dialog.dialog({
    ...
    open:function(){
        $dialog.load("/user/edit/"+id, function(){
            //todo: handle form events
        });
      }
  });
  $dialog.dialog("open");
}
```

You can also make the open dialog function in a static method, like:

```
MvcSolution.Dialog = function (id, title, options) {
  var $dialog = $("#" + id);
  if ($dialog.length == 0) {
    $dialog = $("<div id='" + id + "' class='dialog' title='" + title + "'></div>").appendTo("body");
  }
  $dialog.dialog(options);
  $dialog.dialog("open");
};
```

You can find a good c# and js framework for MVC [here](https://mvcsolution.codeplex.com)